# The existence of the map between cohomology groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety over a field $K$ of characteristic $0$ and $ f: Y\rightarrow X$ be a closed immersion of $X$. If $Y^{'}$ is another closed sub-variety of $X$ and denote the inverse image of $Y^{'}$ under $f$ by $Z=f^{-1}(Y^{'})$. Then we have a common diagram 
   $$Z\rightarrow Y^{'}$$
           $$\downarrow~~~\downarrow$$ 
         $$Y\rightarrow X$$

For any algebraic vector bundle $E$ over $X$, do we have map $Ext^{*}(X;\mathcal{O}_{{Y'}},E)\rightarrow Ext^{*}(Y;\mathcal{O}_{Z},f^{*}E)$?
In the case of complex manifold the map exists indeed. (See: Duality and intersection
theory in complex manifolds. I; Dommingo Teledo and Yue Lin L. Tong ) There exists such a map for algebraic variety? how to do that in algebraic language without analysis, I cann't. Any idea?